# Jsoup: 500 error loading URL

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to write code which logs into the Google Play website and extracts the data present in the home page of the developer.

Now when I try to parse the URL: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/Home?dev_acc=12345678, it just parses the irrelevant parts of the page. The part of the page which contains the Application Data is not present. I saw the source of the same page in a browser and found that the Application Data is not present in it too.

So while using Live HTTP Headers (with Firefox) I found that there are other URLs too which might have the data I want. But when I try to open them (using POST) it gives an error:

```
500 error loading URL https://play.google.com/apps/publish/feedback?dev_acc=12345678
```

Now I tried opening the same page in the browser and I got,

```
HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
Error 405
```

Can someone point out how to carry on with this? I cannot post the code due to my company policy but I can tell you that I have successfully used the same technique in most of the sites and it worked. Cannot understand what's happening here.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

Well... I don't know much about the google API, nor policy. But I know them from not liking guys to get their data without using their own methods. You should look for a way within google to get what you want.

About the error: 500 - Internal Server Error. I think they're probably not allowing you to get the data..

Also, I'd take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/DeveloperGuide). It's google's own API. It might get you where you want.